# Can't get the correct number of points, dynamic quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I'm doing a dynamic quiz because I want to learn javascript, jquery, html and css.

My quiz is supposed to add 1 pt to the score variable each time the answer is correct. It seems to work correctly but when I answer the **10 questions correctly its displays 9 correct answers**.

I'll appreciate if someone could help me.

This is my html:

```
<body>
<header>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>This is my Dynamic Quiz</h1>
        <h2>Using html5 / css / javascript</h2>
    </hgruop>
</header>

<section id='description'>
    <p>This quiz is compossed by 10 questions, you have to answer at least 7 from 10 to pass the exam.</p>
    <h2>Lets start!</h2>
</section>

<div id='questions-number'>
    <p>Question <span id='current-question'>1</span> of <span>10</span> </p>
</div>

<section id='questions'>
    <p id='question'></p>

    <form id='myForm'>
        <input type='radio' name='quiz' id='0' value='0'/><label id='answer0'>answer0</label></li></br>
        <input type='radio' name='quiz' id='1' value='1'/><label id='answer1'>answer1</label></br>
        <input type='radio' name='quiz' id='2' value='2'/><label id='answer2'>answer2</label></br>
        <input type='radio' name='quiz' id='3' value='3'/><label id='answer3'>answer3</label></br>
    </form> 
</section>
<div id='score'></div>
<div id='back'>
    back
</div>
<div id='next'>
    next
</div>
```

and this is my js file

```
$(document).on('ready', ready);
function ready(){
var allQuestions =
[
    {
        question: "Whats my real name?",
        choices: ["Jhonnatan", "Alberto", "Tatan","Jaime"],
        answer: 0
    },

    {
        question: "Who is Colombia's president?",
        choices: ["Alvaro Uribe", "Andres Pastrana", "Juan Manuel Santos","Tatan"],
        answer: 2
    },

    {
        question: "My favorite super heroe?",
        choices: ["Batman", "Flash", "Tatan","Javascript"],
        answer: 3
    },

    {
        question: "Wich sports do i practice?",
        choices: ["Climbing", "Swimming", "Programming","Running"],
        answer: 0
    },

    {
        question: "Whats my dad's name?",
        choices: ["Alberto", "Jorge", "Javier","Jose"],
        answer: 1
    },

    {
        question: "Whats my favorite color?",
        choices: ["Red", "Purple", "Blue","All"],
        answer: 2
    },

    {
        question: "My favorite alcoholic drink",
        choices: ["Vodka", "Aguardiente", "Rum","Tekila"],
        answer: 3
    },

    {
        question: "Whats my favorite kind of music?",
        choices: ["Hardcore", "Reggaeton", "Salsa","Programming"],
        answer: 0
    },

    {
        question: "How many qestions has this quiz??",
        choices: ["20", "8", "10","12"],
        answer: 2
    },

    {
        question: "My favorite programming lenguage?",
        choices: ["Ruby", "Arduino", "Python","Javascript"],
        answer: 3
    }
];

var score = 0;
var number=0;
var question = $('#question');
var choice1 = $('#answer0');
var choice2 = $('#answer1');
var choice3 = $('#answer2');
var choice4 = $('#answer3');
var next = $('#next');
var back = $('#back');
var currentQuestion = $('#current-question');

next.on('click', changeQuestion);
addQuestionAndAnswers();    
back.on('click', backQuestion);



function addQuestionAndAnswers() {
    currentQuestion.text(number + 1);
    question.text(allQuestions[number].question);
    choice1.text(allQuestions[number].choices[0]);
    choice2.text(allQuestions[number].choices[1]);
    choice3.text(allQuestions[number].choices[2]);
    choice4.text(allQuestions[number].choices[3]);
    console.log('funcionando!');
}


function changeQuestion(){
    if($("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").length == 1){
        if(number<9){
            if($("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").val() == allQuestions[number].answer){
                number = number +1;
                score ++;
                addQuestionAndAnswers();
            }else{
                number = number +1;
                addQuestionAndAnswers();
            }
        }else{
            displayResult();
    }
        console.log('checked answer');
    }else{
        alert('please select an answer before proceed');
    }



    function displayResult(){
        currentQuestion.text('10');
        $('#myForm').css('display', 'none');
        $('#question').css('display', 'none');
        $('#next').css('display', 'none');
        $('#score').css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('#score').text('Your score is: ' + score + 'pts');


    }
}

function backQuestion(){
    if(number > 0){
        number = number -1;
        addQuestionAndAnswers();
    }


}
}
```

[edit]

this is the jsfiddle demo :)

http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/Wn8Qg/1/

Comment: help if you provide an idea whare you think problem lies in the code. Also really help if you create a live demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: well i thins is in the if statement inside the changeQuestion function, when number reach nine it doesnt add the last pint to the score var, but if i use (if number <= 9) adds me another number and then act like if were 11 questions...ill post the fiddle in a couple of minutes im just updating it with this code

Comment: I think your problem is that when clicking next on the last question, you directly call `displayResult` instead of entering the if condition and computing the score.

Comment: That's a lot of code you expect us to examine. If you want to learn JavaScript, you have to learn [how to debug it](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: Now I have to give 10 right answers after I have created a JSFiddle. Please help us and make a Fiddle next time.

Comment: i already posted the fiddle! :(

Comment: since you are using `console.log()` and have idea where problem might be, log actual variables to see what values they have at different points in the application... see if they are what is expected. You might be adding something too soon. Can log as many variables at one time as you want. Also scale demos down to less questions and provide cheat sheet (answers on display) to make it easy for others to help test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at where you're incrementing the score:

```
if (number < 9) {
    if ($("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").val() == allQuestions[number].answer) {
        number = number + 1;
        score++;  // only gets incremented here!!!
        addQuestionAndAnswers();
    } else {
        number = number + 1;
        addQuestionAndAnswers();
    }
} else {
    displayResult();
}
```

So when you submit the last question, it doesn't check the answer. You should re-arrange this part of the code, perhaps like this:

```
// first, check answer
if ($("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").val() == allQuestions[number].answer) {
    score++;  // increment score for correct answer
}
// then, move to next question OR show results
if (number < 9) {
    number = number + 1;
    addQuestionAndAnswers();
} else {
    displayResult();
}
```

You have another bug too: if you answer a question correctly, then go back to it, then click `next`, it adds to your total score again! So you can get infinite points if you want.

Comment: don't even need to check an answer after first one, radios stay checked so can go right to end also

Comment: ohhh yeah!i just added the back button so i was working on it but then i found  the bug on the score  :p....i'm also aware of the radio buttons stayed check, but i dont understand why they still checked because in the html i dont have the checked property active for any of the radio buttons.

Comment: They are not created again for every question, so they stay active after clicked. You just have to make them unchecked on every new question.

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez: They stay checked because you never re-create the radio buttons; you just change the text next to them. You'll have to explicitly uncheck them. Try `$("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").prop('checked', false);` to uncheck them.

Comment: ohhh thank you very much i didnt noticed that was happening i tought was a property in the html that i didnt assign or somehting like that but you are right, i just change text but never reset the radio buttons!